# Place 3D object using iOS 11 ARKit(Scenekit) only if proper horizontal plane is detected

Tags: scenekit, ios11, xcode9-beta, arkit

I developed a POC using iOS 11 ARKit(Scenekit- https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/PlacingObjects.zip). When i try to place a 3D object using camera, it detects horizontal planes and placing it.

But i am able to place the object anywhere(like in the air) even if it doesn't detect proper horizontal plane which is not an ideal scenario.

Is it possible to restrict user such that the object can be placed only in valid horizontal planes like floor and not anywhere else? That is i want to detect the level of the floor and place objects only above valid planes and not on the air.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit `ARHitTestResult` of user touch event by specifying hit test option `ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingExtent`.

```
CGPoint tapPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.sceneView];
NSArray<ARHitTestResult *> *result = [self.sceneView hitTest:tapPoint types:ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingExtent];
```

Then place object selected at position specifying in `ARHitTestResult.worldTransform`.
This will ensure user can only place object on planes ARKit has detected.

Comment: I am not allowing user to select the position of surface to place the object. When the user taps add object i am placing the object at the center of surface(screen) where the focus square is currently present. Then user can drag the object and place it anywhere they like just like the PlacingObjects demo. I am not able to detect whether the focus square is pointed towards the floor with surface detected or somewhere flying in the air.

Comment: Just replace tapPoint to center of focus square, which I guess is center of your view.